# Linking a domain name to Rackspace Cloud

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I'm new to server management and wanted some advice on how to do it.

Here is what I did so far:

1. On the registrar of our domain name I setted the Rackspaces' nameservers (dns1.stabletransit.com & dns2.stabletransit.com)
2. On the server's Linux, I created a virtual host to link the domain name with the right folder (It works).
3. In the Rackspace admin interface, I added the new domain like this:

   ```
   Name                    Content                 Domain  Name        TTL (Seconds)   Type
   *.<the domain name>     <the instance IP>       <the domain name>   300             A
   <the domain name>       <the instance IP>       <the domain name>   300             A
   www.<the domain name>   <the domain name>       <the domain name>   300             CNAME
   <the domain name>       dns1.stabletransit.com  <the domain name>   3600            NS
   <the domain name>       dns2.stabletransit.com  <the domain name>   3600            NS
   ```

I don't know yet if it will work because I have to wait for the DNS to be dispatched among the DNS servers.

But here is what I don't understand: The Rackspace instance won't let me delete the 2 last line containing NS types. And I thought that I could remove them as I already declared these type in my registrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the last 2 lines are not required.

You can test if your domains are resolvable by Rackspace DNS with the following command,

```
$ dig @dns1.stabletransit.com <your domain name>
```

Try deleting all entries and recreating them without the last 2 lines.

Comment: Yes, the dig command displays the 2 NS entries and I can't delete them. But after all, I realize that I can keep those 2 NS entries because they are correct? I will go back to this issue when my DNS will be propagated. Thanks.

Comment: It works like expected, even if I didn't delete those 2 lines. Cheers